# Resources for Rocket Propulsion

Tags: rockets, propulsion, reference-request, thermodynamics

I am a Mechanical Engineering student who is very much interested in Rocket propulsion. Lately I have been searching for good resources to learn concepts about rocket propulsion. I'd be glad to get some suggestions on where to get started with the subject and what are the different domains I need to learn in order to get a good grasp of the subject.

I tried searching the internet but ended up with tonnes of videos and pages which left me behind in a confused state about where to get started.

Comment: I have heard https://space.stackexchange.com is pretty good…  ex-NASA folks even hang out there from time to time.

Comment: @JacobKrall but I heard that nobody goes there any more; it's too crowded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good starting point would be this very site's rather comprehensive reference section, which contains many propulsion references:

[Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/resources-and-references-on-the-topic-of-space-exploration)

If you are looking for an introductory text, one of the links there might be useful - namely

> [An Introduction to Rocket Missile Propulsion](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015002938747&view=1up&seq=7&skin=2021) Rocketdyne Technical Training publication that covers basic rocket equations in a simplified manner. Annoying page-at-a-time viewer but a valuable resource.

Comment: This really helps. Thanks @Organic Marble

Comment: @PrasannaB glad to hear it! Welcome to space stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Everyday Astronaut has a playlist called [Rocket Deep Dives](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWzKfs3icbT6yhDTpO1GyDlz9AXdWSiGr) that might interest you. Since you’re a mechanical engineer, “Why don’t rocket engines melt?” and “Rocket engine cycles” would be very good starting points to whet your appetite.